# jQuery get all divs with specific id

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

i Stackoverflow,

I'm trying to get my head around make tooltips to show a description for each item in my asp:Repeater control. The problem is my jquery have to loop through all the divs and make a .tooltip(). I have tried to use the each() function in jQuery, but there's no tooltip showing up :-/

My current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip').each(function (index, domEle) {
        domEle.tooltip();
    });
});
</script>
```

And my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListPartners" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>  
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px; height: 18px; width:400px;">
            <div id="data_tooltip_from_div" style="display:none;"> <%#Eval("profile") %></div>
                 <a id="tooltip_from_div" href="#" class="tooltip"> <%#Eval("name") %>, <%#Eval("address") %>, <%#Eval("zip") %> <%#Eval("city") %> <a href='<%#Eval("homepage") %>' target="_blank"><img src='/kort/www.png' /></a></a>
            </td>
            <td style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px; height: 18px;"><%#Eval("phone") %></td>               
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Is this approach totally off, or? :-)

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "all divs with a specific id"? An id is **unique**, there can be only one.

Comment: And break your question down. "Why doesn't this JS work on this ASP?" is a much harder problem to deal with than "Why doesn't this JS work on this HTML?" or "Why doesn't this ASP output this HTML?"

Comment: @David - you mean **should** be unique. That's the spec, though I have seen this ignored too often :(

Comment: Ah, yes of course :) don't know what I was thinking about honestly. I meant "for every <a id="tooltip_from_div" href="#" class="tooltip">" I need to make that as a tooltip()

Comment: @Oded — and then browsers break when parsing trying to access elements with JS using their ids. :( (If you are trying to reuse an id, fix that first)

Comment: @bomortensen - Your code should work since you're going off class, but remove that invalid repeated ID :)

Comment: hmm. You appear to be trying to call `HTMLElementNode.tooltip()`, but there is no such method. AFAIK there isn't a `jQueryObject.tooltop()` either (unless there is some unspecified third party plugin at work here)

Comment: Are there some nested <a> tags in there too, I'm not sure if that's valid, and could be complicating matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `domEle` refers to the DOM element directly, not a jQuery object that has the `.tooltip()` plugin method...so it should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip').each(function (index, domEle) {
        $(domEle).tooltip();
    });
});
```

But...it's a plugin, so there's no need to loop at all:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip').tooltip();
});
```

IDs have to be unique...it's not causing the error here but remove it if it's repeated to be valid and avoid other issues later.  You already have the class you need to select the elements you're after here.

---

Also, you should be seeing a JavaScript error in your console with your current approach, this will tell you exactly what's going on.  If you're in a browser without a console I'd recommend grabbing Firefox and [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to go with it, or Chrome and it's included developer tools.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your answer! :) It works, but the problem is that all the tooltips shows the first <%#Eval("profile") %> So it would seem as I should do some kind of loop to apply the tooltip() to each <a> element (?)

Comment: @bomortensen - I take it your full `.tooltip()` call looks something like `content: '#data_tooltip_from_div'`?  Can you post that code?

Comment: Hi again Nick, nope - I have just looked at the jquery.tooltip plugin and theres strangely enough no content: "attribute".. I'm quite confused about how this call actually works I must say

Comment: However, it just struck me that in my repeater I'm having both a div an <a> element which both has id's- so basically I'm outputting the same id for every single record.

Comment: @bomortensen - I would need to see the tooltip plugin you're using to give you advice on how to fix...do you have a link?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes of course :) This is the plugin I'm using: http://www.nuanceweb.dk/tooltip.jquery.txt

Comment: @bomortensen - does the object you're evaling have an ID?  The plugin looks for the `id` of the link and just prepends it with `data_` for the tooltip...so id you had a unique ID for each it would also work.

Comment: Ahh, well spotted! :) So basically I have to do it like this: <a id="tooltip_from_div<%#Eval("id") %>" ? So the id of the <a> element is unique

Comment: @bomortensen - yup, and use that same suffix on the `<div>`:  `<div id="data_tooltip_from_div<%#Eval("id") %>">`

Comment: Beautiful!! That indeed works like a charm :) Even without looping in jQuery. Thanks a lot for your help and patience Nick! Much appreciated!